# Only Clipping part of a vector layer with QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, clip

What tool I would use if I just wanted to clip one area in a vector layer?  I want to be able to make the red line extent match the green border, without clipping out the rest of the red extent (which is off screen).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Setting:**

[image]

**With Line Layer --> Lines to Polygons:**

[image]

**With new Polygon from Lines AND Polygon --> Symetrical Difference**

[image]

**With Result of Symetrical Difference  --> Multipart to Singleparts**

[image]

**Delete Parts you want keep**

You can although invert a selction to simplify the slection process.

[image]

**With Result from Lines to Polygons and the Singlepart --> Difference**
[image]

**With Difference --> Polygons to Lines**

[image]

Not a very smart solution, but if you need it just once than it works.
Another solution could although be to trace the line you want and merge it with your existing line or use polygons to line and extract the part you need, which is the best solution if you just want the oultines of your green polygon.